# Excel 2007 VBA runtime error when selecting worksheet with variable

Tags: excel, vba

I've been recently getting back into VBA and have been testing out a concept of Adding Worksheets by the string in a variable. I've been able to get the worksheets to add successfully and the last two lines of my code are simply to select the sheet name of the variable and then select cell A + the row number that is stored in another variable

In Sheet1, Column A, starting in A1,  I have a list of 8 different names that cycles through:

- Bob
- Jeff
- Max
- Steve
- Rosie
- Pippa
- Penelope
- Rob

I am expecting the macro to end on Sheet "Rob" with cell A9 selected, however i get a runtime 1004 error

I have stepped through the code and it is selecting the sheet correctly with the variable, but when it tries to select row A9, the error presents

My code is below:

```
Sub Add_worksheets()

Dim sheetName As String
Dim rownum As Integer

rownum = 1
Range("A" & rownum).Select
sheetName = ActiveCell.Value

Do Until Range("A" & rownum).Value = ""
Range("A" & rownum).Select
sheetName = CStr(ActiveCell.Value)
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = sheetName
Sheets("sheet1").Select
rownum = rownum + 1
Loop

Sheets(sheetName).Select
Range("A" & rownum).Select

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also suggest you add `if-else` to check if the sheet name exists.. Why do you want to `select`? I do not support selections, since you need it you may try this: Because when you are incrementing `rownum` it goes to 10th cell, that means, Sheetname no longer has a name but empty..

```
Dim sheetName As String
Dim rownum As Integer
Dim WS as WorkSheet

rownum = 1
sheetName = Range("A" & rownum).Value '-- remove select


Do Until Range("A" & rownum).Value = ""
Range("A" & rownum).Select
sheetName = CStr(ActiveCell.Value)
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = sheetName
Set WS = Sheets(sheetName)
Sheets("sheet1").Select
rownum = rownum + 1
Loop

rownum = rownum - 1 '-- here
WS.Activate
Range("A" & rownum).Value = rownum
```

Or you may just use an array to do the creation of the sheets and then ***select*** a sheet later....Instead of going back and forth to first sheet...with names..

```
Sub addSheets()
Dim rowNum as Integer
Dim Ws as WorkSheet
Dim vArray as Variant

'-- creates one dimensional array
vArray = WorkSheetFunction.Transpoe(Sheets(1).Range("A1:A9")) 

For rownum = Lbound(vArray) to Ubound(vArray)
   If IsEmpty(vArray(rowNum)) Then
      On Error Resume Next
      Set Ws = Sheets(vArray(rowNum))
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then '--no such sheet, so add it
         Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = vArray(rowNum)
         Set Ws = Sheets(vArray(rowNum))
      End If
   End IF
Next rownum

Ws.Activate
Ws.Range("A1").offset(rownum).value = rownum
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response

The reason i was using the select function was simply to highlight the active cell so i knew it had stored all parameters as expected. I've copied your code in and had no error, however it replaced the last value of my list

As i mentioned above, this is merely to test the concept of it as i will be implementing it into a larger 'project' that i am undertaking. I will be needing to select the sheet set in the variable and perform functions on the sheet. I could simply index them, but the need for variables is essential for the long term goals

Comment: So other than replacing is everything fitting well? Can I assume that you know how to remove the replacement of last cell? does your code that I changed working? And btw you may run any function as long as you set the worksheet and give it as a parameter to the function, doesn't necessarily need to select the sheet.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I've been able to get something working by combining both yours and my ideas. Appreciate the help

Comment: No need to appologize `;)` as long as you got it worked out, that's great to hear.